# How to install pycurl on a win32 machine without compiling

Tags: python

Please bear with me as I am completely new to programming/python, etc.

I am attempting to install the pycurl module on my local win32 machine. I do not know anything about compiling, and I have attempted to install the module through an msi installer located here:

http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/download/

and I am using the **pycurl-7.19.5.win32-py3.4.msi** download, with Python 3.4.

I have downloaded it, and when I attempt to run a python query using the command prompt, I receive the error:

ImportError: No module named 'pycurl'

When I run the script without importing pycurl, it runs fine, so I know I have python installed successfully.

What am I doing wrong? I don't want to resort to compiling as that is going in completely foreign territories for me. I'd like to learn how to install modules into python for future purposes as well.

Comment: you have multiple versions of python installed ...

Comment: If you can, try Requests instead of PyCurl. Requests is much simpler to use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try installing `pycurl` from [this site](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pycurl), where all modules are as Windows binaries. Installing it and then trying to `import pycurl` works fine for me (you have to download appropiate `.whl` for your Python version & platform, then run):

```
..\Downloads>pip install pycurl-7.19.5.3-cp35-none-win32.whl
Installing collected packages: pycurl
Successfully installed pycurl-7.19.5.3

..\Downloads>python
Python 3.5.0 (v3.5.0:374f501f4567, Sep 13 2015, 02:16:59) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
>>> import pycurl
>>> pycurl
<module 'pycurl' from 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Python 3.5\\lib\\site-packages\\pycurl.cp35-win32.pyd'>
```

The problem you describe may happen when you have multiple versions of Python installed without using `virtualenv`.

Comment: to avoid using a wrong `pip` command, `python -m pip` could be used

Comment: turns out I had Python 3.4 and 3.5 installed. I have it working now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `pip` instead:

```
pip install pycurl
```

**Edit 2020-12-11:**

Pycurl no longer builds binaries. The last binaries available are for Python 3.4 or 3.5.

If you're still using Python 3.4/3.5, and you don't want to/can't build from source, you can install the last available official binary builds from pip using:

```
pip3 install --only-binary :all: pycurl
```

WARNING: the latest binary build may be behind the latest source version and therefore have security bugs.

Comment: Installing pycurl with pip tends not to work, based on multiple posts on this site and others.

Comment: @user3273814 it looks like you're new to SO. You do not downvote answers that you don't work for **you** in the present day. This command is from the Pycurl docs and in 2015, worked fine for Win Py34/Py35 as requested by the OP. On Mac and Linux, the command still works. It's certainly not a good way to get people to help you. It gives me no motivation to help your problem