# Trouble with installing pycurl in Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, pycurl

I tried installing pycurl with the .msi installer on Windows. After installing, I tried to import the module pycurl. This is what I got:

```
Python 3.9.1 (tags/v3.9.1:1e5d33e, Dec  7 2020, 17:08:21) [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pycurl
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pycurl'
>>>
```

Comment: Do you have a virtual environment?

Comment: No, this is ordinary Windows 10. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: This post appears to have the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33684195/how-to-install-pycurl-on-a-win32-machine-without-compiling?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Try installing pycurl with pip

```
pip install pycurl
```

use pip3 if pip doesn't works.

Comment: I tried pip, but it couldn't find libcurl.

Comment: okay.
This happens in windows.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507927/how-do-i-install-pycurl
Try this link it may help